# onBlur killing onClick but not if setTimeout is used

Tags: javascript, onclick, settimeout, onblur

If you put cursor in the first input, then click the button, you get one message.

If you put the cursor in the second one (with the `setTimeout`), you get both messages.

Why doesn't the 'button was clicked' message display in the first scenario?

Conversely, what is it about the `setTimeout` that makes the second one show both alerts?

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    function testOne() {
      alert('button was clicked');
    }
    function testTwo() {
      alert ('focus left the input');
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <input name="input1" onblur="testTwo()" />
  <input name="input2" onblur="setTimeout(function(){testTwo();}, 100)" />
  <button name="button1" onclick="testOne()">Button</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you think is happening, is not really happening.

Try it with `console.log` (which does not block) rather than `alert` (which does block) and you'll see that both event handlers do run. Hooray, one more reason to despise `alert` debugging.

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/j4cuG/

Comment: +1, the blocking nature of alert() is stopping the button from actually being 'clicked' when you click on it from input1

Comment: Thanks Matt x2.  Ah, so the nature of the alert is such that, from the DOM's perspective, I technically never even really clicked the button (in the single alert scenario)?

Comment: That's correct. `alert` brings all JavaScript execution to a **complete, dead halt.**